# ¿Cómo combinar gráficos base con lattice?

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente código reproducible:

```
library (vegan)

data(dune)
data(dune.env)
pool <- with(dune.env, specpool(dune, Management))

layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))

boxplot(specnumber(dune) ~ Management, data = dune.env,
        col = "hotpink", border = "cyan3")
boxplot(specnumber(dune)/specpool2vect(pool) ~ Management,
        data = dune.env, col = "hotpink", border = "cyan3")

# Segundo gráfico
data(BCI)
## Accumulation model
pool <- poolaccum(BCI)
plot(pool)
```

Básicamente son 2 gráficos `base`  de tipo `boxplot` y un gráfico `lattice` (`poolaccum(BCI)`), quiero combinar los tres en uno solo, probé con `layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))`, consigo que los `boxplots` se combinen uno al lado del otro, pero no consigo hacer que el terecero vaya debajo de estos. Se dibuja de forma independiente y solitaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que estás combinando un gráfico base como `boxplot()` con uno de `lattice`. Combinar distintos sistemas gráficos suele ser problemático, aunque en teoría es posible hacerlo mediante el paquete `gridextra`. Pero creo que no vale la pena, te sugiero que unifiques el sistema gráfico directamente a  `lattice` que por lo que veo es el el que usa `vegan`. Hacer esto, representa simplemente reemplazar los `boxplot()` por `bwplot()`. Y luego podemos, ahora si, usar `gridextra` para "acomodar" las gráficas

```
require(gridExtra)
require(lattice)
library (vegan)

data(dune)
data(dune.env)
pool <- with(dune.env, specpool(dune, Management))

bp1 <- bwplot(specnumber(dune) ~ Management, data = dune.env,
        col = "hotpink", border = "cyan3", xlab="", ylab="")
bp2 <- bwplot(specnumber(dune)/specpool2vect(pool) ~ Management,
        data = dune.env, col = "hotpink", border = "cyan3", xlab="", ylab="")


data(BCI)
pool <- poolaccum(BCI)
lp <- plot(pool)

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(bp1, bp2, ncol = 2),
             lp,                             
             nrow = 2)
```

Los tres gráficos deberemos asignarlos a una variable para luego organizarlos mediante `grid.arrange()`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]